# Carousel image size problem with different sized images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]
In my ecommerce project, I'm creating a carousel but, unfortunately, the size of each image is different. I want all images to fit the same size frame despite their original sizes.

[image]

[image]

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide w-100 p-3 h-1" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <h1>Hot & Trends</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="media/images/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="First Product">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Product Name</h5>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="media/images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Second Product">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Product Name</h5>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="media/images/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Third Product">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Product Name</h5>
        <p>Description</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: remove `img-fluid` class and give set width and height to be `100%`

Comment: i know this way, but how about if the screen size changes? plus, if i do this way, the caption becomes weird. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay let me try to fix your `HTML` wait

Answer (score 0):

select the img and set width and heigh of image 100% 
the problem will solve

Comment: .carousel-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

Comment: did you try both 100%?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML-Code:**

```
<section id="slider">
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-right mb-5">
                    <h5 class="display-3">Product Name</h5>
                    <p class="lead">Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-right mb-5">
                    <h5 class="display-3">Product Name</h5>
                    <p class="lead">Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-right mb-5">
                    <h5 class="display-3">Product Name</h5>
                    <p class="lead">Description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>

    <a href="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</section>
```

**CSS-Code:**

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 450px;
  }

  .carousel-image-1 {
    background: url('../image/image1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

This will work fine..

Answer (score 0):

Look like this example. I hope it is as you imagined it. Now you just have to adjust your code like this ...

```css
.carousel {
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel-item,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-item {
  text-align: center;
}

#portfolio {
  background: #356;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="portfolio" class="page-section">
      <div id="reviews" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class='img-fluid'  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2409628/pexels-photo-2409628.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                <p>Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class='img-fluid'  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542141372-98a047557466?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=752&q=80" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                <p>Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```